# Из string в byte[] (C#)

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, byte

Есть небольшой кусок кода, его смысл заключался в том чтобы из массива (в котором приходили подобные цифры 123.1.512.61 в разных комбинациях) передавать в textbox только цифры **(пример: 123 в firstBox.Text; 1 в secondBox.Text и т.д.)**. Но что-то пошло не так, у меня на данный момент приходят все подряд по одному символу **(1; 2; 3; .; и тд.)**

Как это исправить?

```
public void SetByteArray(string userOutput)
        {
            byte[] userOutputBytes = new byte[4];

            if (userOutput != null)
            {
                userOutputBytes = userOutput.Split(new[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 8))
                    .ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                userOutput = "123.0.10.321";
                userOutputBytes = userOutput.Split(new[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 8))
                    .ToArray();
            }

            firstBox.Text = Convert.ToString(userOutput[0]);
            secondBox.Text = Convert.ToString(userOutput[1]);
            thirdBox.Text = Convert.ToString(userOutput[2]);
            fourthBox.Text = Convert.ToString(userOutput[3]);
        }
```

Comment: Банальная опечатка, вы заполняете массив, но потом его не используете

Comment: @АндрейNOP заметил, спасибо!

Comment: Я там ещё комментарий к коду добавил в ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в этой строчке

```
userOutput[0]
```

В этой операции вы берёте 0 символ из userOutput, который равен "123.0.10.321".
Получаете "1".

Вам же надо брать первый элемент массива токенов, который вы получаете позже, а не строки.

В вашем коде это `userOutputBytes` .

То есть вы перепутали входные и выходные данные `userOutputBytes` и `userOutput`.

Кроме того, вы из строк делаете массив байтов `Convert.ToByte(s, 8)`, а потом обратно преобразуете в строчку `Convert.ToString` не вижу в этом смысла.

PS: Основную функцию надо за `if` вынести.

Comment: Да, понял) 
`Кроме того, вы из строк делаете массив байтов Convert.ToByte(s, 8), а потом обратно преобразуете в строчку Convert.ToString не вижу в этом смысла.` А как бы вы сделали на моем месте?
Ну так чтобы из "123.0.10.321" использовать числа "123", "0", "10", "321", и т.д.

Comment: @MiT, ну достаточно же просто Split и всё, у вас массив строк